# Storing cookie data on server

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have  js client code which fires some event x  every time user  open my url xyz.com.I want to increment the count everytime user open the url

key   value
count  1    and updated to 2 when it is   hit again .
How can i do this?

Comment: For accurate records, you'd need to sync that with a server somewhere.

Comment: yes i want to sync in server

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to Google Analytics?

Comment: well if you are open to php,its a two min task..and u have to store the count somewhere in the db..its not possible to keep a count with only javascript..cookies,localstorage are of no use according to ur question

Comment: Yes somethign similar to GA

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the very top of your script:

```
<?php
session_start();
$HIT=1;
$total=$from_db_count+$HIT;
//create function that generates the total hits from DB and return $from_db_count
?>
```